# How do we set default value for log4j2 log level instead of environment variable

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I'm working with log4j2 configuration xml where in i'm using the environment variable for setting the log level something like this

```
<Root level="${env:LOG_LEVEL}">
```

But i want to have some default value in case env var is not set i tried defining some properties in xml but no luck.Thanks

Answer (score 18):

I believe you can specify a default value by specifying another colon followed by a hyphen:

```
${env:LOG_LEVEL:-WARN}
```

Comment: You can also define a property with the same name and it will be used as the default.